# How can I print a jsPDF document with electron?

Tags: electron, jspdf

I have created a pdf document with jsPDF and jspdf-autotable but I am not able to print it with electron.
Electron just allows me to print the contents on the web/html, it is not allowing me to pass the document in any function a print it directly
I also tried window.print() but it crashes my application

Solutions are welcome....

window.print() crashes the application

```
// Electron Configuration
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
let mainWindow = null;
app.on('ready', () => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    })
    mainWindow.loadFile('./index.html')
})

//HTML configuration
<script>
        const jsPDF = require('jspdf')
        const pdf = () => {
            var doc = new jsPDF();
            doc.text('hahahahaha', 10,10)
            window.print(doc.output('bloburl'), 'Print')
        }

    </script>
```

I am expecting the electron app to print my jsPDF document.